# $parse AngularJs Service as described by the official documentation

Tags: angularjs

I am in reference to the AngularJS $parse service as described by the following documentation:
[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24parse)

I am not familiar with the AngularJs documentation and would like to know what those mean:

- `{object=}`
- `{?function(context, value)}`

What does the `=` sign mean in the context of the AngularJs documentation?

What does the `?` mark mean in the context of the AngularJs documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are annotations derived from the Closure Compiler annotations (https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler).

Answer (score 2):

- `{object=}`

This is just notation for a locals object.

A locals object might look like: `{local:{value:'isSet'}}`

where the `object` (local) is `=` to `{value:'isSet'}`

This is just indicating that the object must be named key-value pair of your local objects.

Here is an example.

```
var context = { stuff:null },
    locals = { local: { value:'isSet' }, local1:'!' },
    parseFunction = $parse("stuff = local.value + local1"),
    result = parseFunction(context,locals);

console.log(context); // -> Object { stuff: 'isSet!' }
console.log(result); // -> 'isSet!'
```

As for `{?function(context, value)}`

That just indicates you need to check for that property's presence as a function before you use it (because it may or may not be defined).

In the case of the above code. Since it is not an 'assignable' expression

```
parseFunction.assign === undefined // true
```

In general the '?' indicates things may or may not be there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed explanation. The code sample you provided is very instructive indeed!